# Add and Edit Data using Single View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am a beginner, I am trying to add and edit data using a single view controller, process works fine, but when I try to click add button, view controller is pushed twice.

[image: View Controller holding Add and Edit buttons]

[image: Edit Screen, Works Fine]

When I try to Open Click

[image: My Designs are not visible]

But When I click Back in the navigation bar, the Screen appears with my designs.

[image: Screen with my designs]

**Code For Launching Add Screen**

```
let MenuAdd = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MenuEdit") as! AdminMenuVC
MenuAdd.IsEdit = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MenuAdd, animated: true)
```

**Code For Launching Edit Screen**

```
let MenuEdit = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MenuEdit") as! AdminMenuVC
MenuEdit.IsEdit = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MenuEdit, animated: true)
```

Comment: check if your button action not called twice or you have already link segue from storyboard.if its link from storyboard you do not need to push programatically then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possible explanation for this:

- You also have a storyboard segue going from the add button to the AdminMenuVC- if this is the case, just delete it (you are already pushing it from code)
- You call from the first VC both `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MenuAdd, animated: true)` and `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MenuEdit, animated: true)` - they both refer to the same VC (AdminMenuVC). I cannot say if this is the case as you haven't posted the code. Be careful to check that you are not calling the two lines of code at the same time

Comment: I had an action segue. Thanks for the explaination.

Answer (score 1):

Check button action you may be setting action and touch up inside actions on same button. You need to remove one action from reference inspector

[image]